# Push Segue Animation Stops working

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboard to create Push Segue to transmit between UIViewControllers. After I open the app these segues are working great but later it stops animation. what is the reason for this . Mainly i am not using any UINavigationController.
I Just want to know am I missing some thing or why its working like that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the apple [documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html)